# Part number and description for broken handle?

Tags: part-identification, parts-replacement

1996 Merlo P23.6-EV-SC

This plastic part for our Merlo broke. What is it called and possibly the part number? I'd like to purchase a new one, but don't know how to look for it to find one.

[image: Merlo broken handle]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sorry to have changed your question so drastically, but questions asking for where to find or purchase help for parts is off-topic for the site. I believe if we can get you these two pieces of information, it would allow you to not only find the part, but it is within the scope of the site, so I won't have to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the terms "1996 Merlo P23.6-EV-SC replacement parts" in my search engine. A number of inapplicable results were presented, but one that appears promising. It seems to be a [broker or a middleman](https://www.urparts.com/index.cfm/page/enquiries/enquiryId/204468/) in that the joystick is a listed item, but one must complete a quote request. The web site indicates that the request would then be passed on to those who might have the desired part.

The other results were not particularly productive, leaving as an option the recreation of the lever knob. Reddit has a couple of related subreddits, one in particular: https://www.reddit.com/r/3Drequests which allows one to post a photo of an item to be designed in the appropriate software. That specific sub is for design requests, while there is another, https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprintmything for requests to have an item printed. The former also allows for printing along with the design, but it's useful to have duplicated posts once the design is created.

For your split handle, I would suggest to remove it and create a series of photos from all angles and especially from the bottom, showing the mounting hole(s). Photos with a scale in the photo showing height, width, etc are also useful to the prospective designer.

When you find a design with which you are satisfied, your request for printing should include the reference of outdoor work. PLA plastic is a common material for 3D printing, but does not fare well in heat. ABS is better in that respect, but is susceptible to UV light. ASA is likely to be the best choice of plastic for the part and you are permitted to request specific materials and colour in the subreddit.

With sufficient photos, especially ones taken at 90° rotations and marked as such, a merely competent maker/creator could duplicate your lever handle. There are designers on the subreddit with qualifications far beyond mine, and charge appropriately.

My research would indicate that this is a UK-local construction rig. The subreddit supports international solutions and I've seen quite a few posts from UK residents.